# Javascript Replace KeyPress on Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, input, replace

**So I was trying replace the key press "K" with "Z" in an input field.**
**I was successfully able to do it**. **But there is a slight delay which makes the user see that the "K" being changed to "Z".**

This is my code:

```
        function prinner (event)
        {
          document.getElementById("txx").innerHTML= event.key; //Displays key pressed on screen by changing text element.
           if(event.keyCode == 32){
               // User has pressed space
               document.getElementById("txx").innerHTML= "Space";
           }
           if (event.key=="k") // Trying to replace this with z.
           {
            var curval = $("#namaye").val(); //namaye is the ID of the input field.
            var nval = curval.slice(0,(curval.length-1))+"z";
            $("#namaye").val(nval);

           }
        }

       $("#namaye").keyup(prinner);
```

Does anyone know a better way to achieve this without the delay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `keydown` instead of `keyup` and cancel the event so the key stroke doesn't actually get printed:

```js
function prinner (event) {

  // Displays key pressed on screen by changing text element.
  document.getElementById("txx").innerHTML= event.key; 
  
  if(event.keyCode == 32){
    // User has pressed space
    document.getElementById("txx").innerHTML= "Space";
  }
  
  // Trying to replace this with z.
  if (event.key=="k") {
  
    var curval = $("#namaye").val(); //namaye is the ID of the input field.
    var nval = curval +"z";
    $("#namaye").val(nval);
    
    // Cancel the event
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
}

$("#namaye").keydown(prinner);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="namaye">
<p id="txx"></p>
```

Comment: You are always preventing default which means that no characters are being sent out to the input.  Given my understanding of the OP, you only want to prevent default on k.  Then, because the 'k' never ends up in the input, you don't have to strip it out with the slice function.  You just have to append z.

Comment: @ConorMancone Did you run my code snippet? Did you type a `k` in the input and see what happens?

Comment: Yes, it turns into a 'z', but no other letters work.  Because you always prevent default you can't actually type in the input box.  Only the letter z will actually appear: I don't believe that is what the op had in mind.

Comment: One more issue: you are still stripping the last character off with your slice function.  Because keydown happens before the input actually changes, you aren't stripping off a 'k' key: you are just stripping off the last key typed.  so if you try to type 'ak' you won't end up with 'az' (as desired), you will just get 'z'.  The OP had the slice because he had to remove the k.  The keydown stops that from happening in the first place, so you just have to append a 'z'

Comment: @ConorMancone Thanks. I was assuming OPs slice code was fine. Updated again.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. This worked but could you tell me why both of these functions are used. event.preventDefault(); and event.stopPropagation(); , I understand it stops the key press event but why two functions and what does each do?

Comment: I tested the code and it works without event.stopPropagation();.

Comment: Just event.preventDefault() works perfect. I don't understand why the event.stopPropagation(); was used?

Comment: @SamThomas `.preventDefault()` cancels the event that is taking place (the `keydown` event). `.stopPropagation()` tells the event not to "bubble" up to other ancestor elements. It may not be needed here, but with `click` events it would be. It is a best practice to do both, unless you have a specific reason not to.

Comment: Ah I see it creates issues when dealing with clicks and not just key presses. Thanks a lot, I understand  now.

Answer (score 3):

Use `keydown` event, and cancel the default behaviour when `k` is pressed. Also, use `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties to replace the characters that were selected at the moment the key was pressed, and to put the cursor at the right position, just after the inserted `z`:

```js
function prinner (event) {
    $("#txx").text(event.keyCode == 32 ? "Space" : event.key); 
    if (event.key=="k") {
        var s = $(this).val();
        var i = this.selectionStart;
        s = s.substr(0, i) + "z" + s.substr(this.selectionEnd);
        $(this).val(s);
        this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = i + 1;
        return false;
    }
}

$("#namaye").keydown(prinner);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="namaye">
<div id="txx"></div>
```

Since you use jQuery, use `$("#....")` instead of the more verbose `document.getElementById("....")`. Also, in the event handler, `this` will be input element, so use that reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try using keydown?  It happens before the input is actually modified: in fact, if you return false (or e.preventDefault()) inside a keydown listener, it will actually cancel the keystroke, which I think is what you want.  Then you manually add your new key.  Something like (untested and skipping some details for clarity):

```
    function prinner (event)
    {
       if (event.key=="k")
       {
           event.preventDefault() // makes sure the 'k' key never goes to the input
           $("#namaye").val( $("#namaye").val() + 'z' );
       }
    }

   $("#namaye").keyup(prinner);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an event.preventDefault() inside your if clause to stop the event propagation and then you can insert your "z" key.